# Installing MongoDB with 'wget' Command

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal

I am having trouble installing MongoDB using the `wget` command. Right now, I am running the following command in Mac's terminal to install Mongo:

```
$ wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.4.4.tgz
```

**Note:** I am using OS X El Capitan.

However, I'm getting an error saying that the `wget` command could not be found. Is there a Mac equivalent of this command that I can run to download MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CURL is your answer.

Here are the steps you need to install MongoDB on a Mac via Terminal

**1**. Download the binary files for the desired release of MongoDB.
Download the binaries from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center.

For example, to download the latest release through the shell, issue the following:

`curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.2.tgz`

**2** 
Extract the files from the downloaded archive.
For example, from a system shell, you can extract through the tar command:

`tar -zxvf mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.2.tgz`

**3** Copy the extracted archive to the target directory.¶
Copy the extracted folder to the location from which MongoDB will run.

```
mkdir -p mongodb
cp -R -n mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.2/ mongodb
```

**4**  Ensure the location of the binaries is in the PATH variable.
The MongoDB binaries are in the bin/ directory of the archive. To ensure that the binaries are in your PATH, you can modify your PATH.

For example, you can add the following line to your shell’s rc file (e.g. ~/.bashrc):

`export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH`

Replace  with the path to the extracted MongoDB archive.

***You can also install MongoDB via HomeBrew***

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Comment: This looks great! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help